# Reordering x axis in barplot(ggplot2) where data is grouped on 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, bar-chart

In exploration of the mpg package in R, I want to plot a bar plot, of x variable as class, y variable as frequency values for class and then stack those bars with cyl.

So, I have first grouped the data set by class and cyl , then added freq for every group.

```
class_count <-
mpg %>% 
group_by(class,cyl) %>%
summarize(freq = n())

class_count %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(class,freq), freq, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

I want the data to be ascending order but in the final plot subcompact bar is coming before
pickup as shown in picture below -

bar plot for the code given above

[image]

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reorder` sorts the bars solely based on `freq` without considering the `class`. Use `fct_reorder`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(class_count, 
      aes(forcats::fct_reorder(class, freq, sum), freq, fill = cyl)) +
 geom_col() + xlab('class')
```

[image]

Comment: It is giving an error ----- Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object '.fun' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: Are you sure you are copying it correctly? I don't get any such error on the data that you have shared.

Comment: I cleaned the global environment and compiled again, then it worked. Thank you so much for your help.